# Куда и что написать что бы можно было возвести в квадрат (#include <cmath.h>). WinForms C++ 215 строчка

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once

namespace Project7 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label5;






    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^ resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm1::typeid));
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(454, 128);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(211, 251);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(214, 128);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 38);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"Рассчитать ";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm1::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(190, 201);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(162, 39);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->label1->Text = L"0";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(52, 66);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(215, 66);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(374, 66);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(533, 66);
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(93, 47);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 16);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label2->Text = L"Xв";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(262, 47);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(23, 16);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 8;
            this->label3->Text = L"Xа";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(412, 47);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(24, 16);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 9;
            this->label4->Text = L"Yв";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(571, 47);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(24, 16);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 10;
            this->label5->Text = L"Yа";
            // 
            // MyForm1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Cornsilk;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(677, 387);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm1";
            this->Text = L"MyForm1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

private: 
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
        int a; //переменная
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;//xв-xа
        int t;//возвожу в квадрат 1 
        a = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
        b = Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text);
        c = Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
        d = Convert::ToInt32(textBox4->Text);
        int e = a - b;// 1 вычитание 
        int t = pow(e, 2);
}
};
}
```